# Creating a primary key with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Im using the code below to create a unique i.d. for primary keys or where every I need them in a program. The code works and there is never any errors but sometimes during debugging I noticed that it does not always increment still with no errors.

Can the code be improved for reliability?

```
- (NSString*)createUniqueID
{

    //create a unique ID

    int currentID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"kUniqueID"] intValue];
    currentID++;

     NSString *returnID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentID];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:returnID forKey:@"kUniqueID"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //added sync

    return returnID;

}
```

Comment: care about thread-safety?

Comment: Thread topic is beyond me at this point. Sorry. working....

Comment: Why use `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`? Just use `integerForKey:` and `setInteger:forKey:`. Then you don't need to convert to/from a string just to increment the value.

Comment: Your right, its better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you need to call synchronize function

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Note that calling `synchronize` is only necessary if the app is killed (such as restarting during debugging) before they are automatically synchronized. The user defaults are actually synchronized on occasion for you as the app runs. I only call `synchronize` when the app goes into the background and after some critical update (just in case the app crashes right after).